Error building android app with react native+expo "Task :expo-modules-core:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a] FAILED"
I've been trying to create a simple login with react native in android, but gradle fails to compile the basic project that comes with expo. I need to test this on emulator for the Firebase login/singin configuration, and the compiling is essencial to build the app.
Steps to reproduce:
npx create-expo-app login-test-app
npx expo prebuild
npx expo run:android

I solved a lot of errors trying to build the app, but for this one I can´t seem to find the answer. I tried deleting the .cxx folder inside \node_modules\expo-modules-core\android, but didn´t work for me. Also tried reinstalling react-native-animated, changing the proyect to a shorter directory.
Here´s what i´ve got:
PS C:\Users\Sofia\Desktop\Universidad\Memoria\login-test-app> npx expo run:android     
› Building app...
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx2048M
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

> Configure project :expo

Using expo modules
  - expo-asset (10.0.10)
  - expo-constants (16.0.2)
  - expo-file-system (17.0.1)
  - expo-font (12.0.10)
  - expo-keep-awake (13.0.2)
  - expo-modules-core (1.12.24)
  - expo-splash-screen (0.27.5)
  - expo-system-ui (3.0.7)
  - expo-web-browser (13.0.3)


> Configure project :react-native-reanimated
Android gradle plugin: 8.2.1
Gradle: 8.8

> Task :expo-modules-core:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a] FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':expo-modules-core:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.
> [CXX1210] C:\Users\Sofia\Desktop\Universidad\Memoria\login-test-app\node_modules\expo-modules-core\android\CMakeLists.txt debug|arm64-v8a : No compatible library foun 

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.8/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.

BUILD FAILED in 27s
301 actionable tasks: 88 executed, 205 from cache, 8 up-to-date
Error: C:\Users\Sofia\Desktop\Universidad\Memoria\login-test-app\android\gradlew.bat app:assembleDebug -x lint -x test --configure-on-demand --build-cache -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 -PreactNativeArchitectures=x86_64,arm64-v8a exited with non-zero code: 1
Error: C:\Users\Sofia\Desktop\Universidad\Memoria\login-test-app\android\gradlew.bat app:assembleDebug -x lint -x test --configure-on-demand --build-cache -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 -PreactNativeArchitectures=x86_64,arm64-v8a exited with non-zero code: 1
    at ChildProcess.completionListener (C:\Users\Sofia\Desktop\Universidad\Memoria\login-test-app\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\build\spawnAsync.js:42:23)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:634:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:519:28)
    at cp.emit (C:\Users\Sofia\Desktop\Universidad\Memoria\login-test-app\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1105:16)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:305:5)
    ...
    at spawnAsync (C:\Users\Sofia\Desktop\Universidad\Memoria\login-test-app\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\build\spawnAsync.js:7:23)
    at spawnGradleAsync (C:\Users\Sofia\Desktop\Universidad\Memoria\login-test-app\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\start\platforms\android\gradle.js:96:48)
    at assembleAsync (C:\Users\Sofia\Desktop\Universidad\Memoria\login-test-app\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\start\platforms\android\gradle.js:74:18)
    at runAndroidAsync (C:\Users\Sofia\Desktop\Universidad\Memoria\login-test-app\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\run\android\runAndroidAsync.js:45:37)

What I'm expecting is to run the code on emulator and also that gradle compiles the project successfully.

I solved this finally! I had in Environment Variables -> System variables, a variable that I added trying to solve older problems I had Variable: _JAVA_OPTIONS, Valor: -Xmx2048m. Deleting this solved my problem. Hope it helps anyone who has this problem too.
